# Python Readline REPL Console Conficts with Gettext (underscore variable)

Tags: python, console, localization, internationalization, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using `gettext` for localization and installs the `gettext()` function to the global `_` variable. However, the readline console I'm using for debug purposes also uses `_` as a special variable to refer to the output of the previous command. Therefore every time I type anything in the console, it overwrites the `_` variable and all my localization blows up.

So, I'd be happy with either of the following:

1. Install `gettext()` to a different variable, or some other best practices for localizing Python packages
2. Stop Readline from assigning the last output to the `_` variable.

The following are at various points within a class:

```
#Install gettext() to global scope
import gettext
gettext.translation('projectname', localedir=os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))+'/locales', languages=[locale]).install()

#Debug console
import code, readline
env = globals().copy()
env['self'] = self
shell = code.InteractiveConsole(env)
shell.interact()
```

I've tried removing and overwriting `_` from the `env` dict (i.e. `env['_'] = None`), but unfortunately Readline seems to set `_` at the global scope regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `gettext.install`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html) mentions to read [another bit about the `names` it installs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.NullTranslations.install) :

> [...] Note that this is only one way, albeit the most convenient way, to make the `_()` function available to your application. Because it affects the entire application globally, and specifically the built-in namespace, localized modules should never install `_()`. Instead, they should use this code to make `_()` available to their module:
>
> ```py
> import gettext
> t = gettext.translation('mymodule', ...)
> _ = t.gettext
> ```

Would it solve your problem ?

Comment: Well, that opens another can of worms. I'd be fine with this if I could define `_` once in a helper module and do `from mymodule.helpers import *` at the top of every file, but apparently `import *` skips the `_` function, and I'd like to avoid putting those three lines at the top of every file. I'm doing that now but naming the function `ï` instead of `_`, which works, but seems not ideal.

Comment: You can define it only once. Put those three lines in their own file, and just import `t` from it. (Maybe use another, clearer name, like `tr` which PyQt uses).